# angucomplete fire event when value is selected in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I'm trying to enable ng-change event for this custom Angular.js directive [angucomplete](https://github.com/darylrowland/angucomplete)

This is how I declare the directive in my html file:

```
    <angucomplete id="Angucomplete1" placeholder="Type 3 letters to start" pause="100" 
selectedobject="selectedCountry" localdata="datasearch" ng-model="modelCountry" searchfields="name" 
titlefield="name" minlength="3" inputclass="form-control form-control-small" matchclass="highlight" />
```

I tried putting ng-change="myFunction()" here which is part of the controller but its not firing at all.

Furthermore, I've tried putting ng-change attribute in the actual directive code as well, but it doesn't work as well:

```
   template: '<div class="angucomplete-holder"><input id="{{id}}_value" ng-change="myFunction()" ng-model="searchStr" type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" class="{{inputClass}}" ng-focus="resetHideResults()" /></div>'
```

Any idea how I can fire event when the actual input value is changed in the textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try angucomplete-alt that I forked from angucomplete, fixed lots of bugs, and added extra features:
http://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/#example10

Attribute names are different for angucomplete-alt. So you you need to change yours like this.

```
<angucomplete-alt id="Angucomplete1" placeholder="Type 3 letters to start" pause="100" 
selected-object="selectedCountry" local-data="datasearch" search-fields="name" 
title-field="name" minlength="3" input-class="form-control form-control-small" matchclass="highlight"/>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried angucomplete-alt it works almost good, but for some reason when the search is happening, the list with possible options is expanding ok but with no text inside, although when I'll select option from the search result its displayed ok in the textbox, only the values which are in the search results have no text although they exist there, what do you think is the problem? Thanks

Comment: It's probably that data is not mapped correctly. Could you paste your code using plnkr or jsbin?

Comment: do you have a minute to connect to my PC via teamviewer so you can see directly? Thanks

Comment: Do you have any idea why ng-model is not working with angucomplete ?

Comment: Because it's not 2-way binding.